# setting column type to json is not working during migration in laravel

Tags: laravel, migration

I' am building a `mysql database` through `laravel` . In the migration file I have set one column to be `json type` , but when I make the `migration` with this command `php artisan migrate:fresh` , the database is created successfully but not with the correct type of the column I have set earlier in the migration file .Below is my migration file code .

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->json('conf');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Here `conf` column' s type is not longer `json` in the my database but rather `longtext type`  after migration .  Why ????.

Comment: Laravel migrates JSON columns to LongText, and that's fine, you can still store json data there

Answer (score 0):

Add this into the model of the table it will help you.

```
class Question extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'conf' => 'array',
    ];
}
```

it will cast the column to an array of objects that you can work with.